# Error message Run time error 1004 Autofilter method or range class failed

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I am trying to create a filter on column C which displays all value except the value a90.

[image]

I get error message:

> Run time error 1004
>   Autofilter method of range class failed

The error comes from this line:

```
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("$A$4:$C$1300").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>*a90*" _
        , Operator:=xlAnd
```

```
Sub classificationfilterwithoutvaluea90 ()
Range("C6").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("$A$4:$C$1300").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>*a90*" _
        , Operator:=xlAnd
End Sub
```

My data in column C are not part of a pivot table whereas my data in column A and B are part of a pivot table.

Comment: Actually, looking over your post again, are you trying to filter `"<>*a90*"` or `"<>a90"` ? They do different things, and you posted conflicting information regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this out, and I think is what you want or at least it should help get what you want.

Couple of things to note though prior. These lines are unnecessary:

```
Range("C6").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
```

First thing is that you should not be letting VBA implicitly decide which range in which worksheet in which workbook that you want to be using. It seems, in this case, that you're trying to get the value of cell C6 for later use, so to do that I would do something like this.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim myVal As String

'pick whichever worksheet you want to work with, i'm just choosing at random here
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
'assigns the value of cell C6 to myVal. CStr() is casting whatever value is in C6 to a string
myVal = CStr(ws.Cells(6,3))
```

As I said previously, you don't really want VBA to be deciding what these variables will be for you, so you should explicitly set them.

```
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("$A$4:$C$1300")
```

Using the `Active` variables usually leads to shooting yourself in the foot. In this case, since you're working with 1 workbook, the `ThisWorkbook` variable is sufficient because - I think - that it is specifying the workbook that is executing the code, but you should also be specifying the worksheet you want to work with.

Here's the code that I tested:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub classificationfilterwithoutvaluea90()
    Dim thisws As Worksheet
    Dim filterArea As Range
    Const filterCrit As String = "<>a90"

    'idk which worksheet you want, so I just picked one
    Set thisws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    'This works as an alternative as well
    'Set thisws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    'setting the range to be filtered
    Set filterArea = thisws.Range("A4:C1300")

    filterArea.AutoFilter _
        Field:=1, _
        Criteria1:=filterCrit, _
        Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you very much Jcrizk, I tested your solution works very well...